# Red star bean Icon

Tags: spring, javabeans, spring-tool-suite

In STS, Spring explorer show red star at right bottom hand side of beans:

[image]

Do you know its meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this shows up when a bean is defined as a prototype.